# Identify if a cell with in text format contains any letters

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a list of around 12,000 identifying numbers that need to be stored as text to preserve leading 0s, and I use `=len` to identify any identifying numbers that are the wrong length, but I can't work out how to quickly identify if a cell contains letters.

`=isnumber` doesn't work as the imported data is stored as text so it says all cells aren't numbers.

Answer can be VBA or formula.

Comment: I don't know a good, short formula for it but an alternative is save a copy of your file. Then in that file convert your data into numbers, then now you can do the =isnumber formula as you stated.

Comment: Something like `=ISERR(A1*1)` will return `TRUE` if A1 can't be coerced to a number.  Might fail with values which can be parsed as (eg) hexadecimal...

Comment: if you're ok with ugly formula, you could do something like substitute...(substitute(a1,"1",""),"2",""...),"9","") and check that the len is 0. Tim William's answer is slicker, but

Comment: Another way. **1.** Type `1` in any blank cell. **2.** Copy that cell. **3.** Highlight your list of 15k numbers and right click-pastespecial. **4.** Uner Paste click "Values" **5.** Under Operation setion , click "Multiply". **6.** Click Ok and now you have all numbers (stored as text) as number for which you can use `=IsNumber`

Comment: Another Way: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2027553&seqNum=11. In fact I just noticed that the above way (using pastespecial) is also mentioned in this link.

Comment: Another way `=ISNUMBER(VALUE(A1))`

Comment: Danny I see you had mentioned `Answer can be VBA or formula but basically,` which @player0 removed from your post. Can you confirm if you are doing this in MS Excel or Google Spreadsheet.?

Answer (score 1):

> =isnumber doesn't work as the imported data is stored as text so says all cells aren't numbers.

Use it with `Value()`

```
=ISNUMBER(VALUE(A1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((LEN(A2:A)<7)*(NOT(ISERR(A2:A*1))), A2:A, ))
```

if the length is under 7 characters and text string is composed of numbers

[image: 0]